# Dissolve a face into a single vertex in the middle

Tags: vertices, faces

Minor issue, I know there's a method of doing this with a name along the lines of "dissolve to middle" or similar, but I don't seem to find anything about it, probably because I'm not searching correctly.

Comment: M > Merge at Center?

Comment: Nevermind I already got it

Comment: So were you looking for merge at center?